# Jack server failed to (re)start

Tags: android, makefile, build

I am trying a build of Android N, but I am constantly getting this error :

```
15:37:13 FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin install-server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-launcher.jar prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.8.ALPHA.jar  2>&1 || (exit 0) ) && (JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS=\"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation\" prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.8.ALPHA.jar 4.8.ALPHA 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-2.28.RELEASE.jar 2.28.RELEASE || exit 47; prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-3.36.CANDIDATE.jar 3.36.CANDIDATE || exit 47; prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-4.7.BETA.jar 4.7.BETA || exit 47 )"
15:37:13 Jack server already installed in "/srv/jenkins/.jack-server"
15:37:13 Launching Jack server java -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation -cp /srv/jenkins/.jack-server/launcher.jar com.android.jack.launcher.ServerLauncher
15:37:13 Jack server failed to (re)start, try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log
15:37:13 No Jack server running. Try 'jack-admin start-server'
15:37:13 No Jack server running. Try 'jack-admin start-server'
```

I put some logs in the `jack-admin` code and I am getting the following error, when I do `./jack-admin start-server`.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8077: No route to host
isServerRunning : Curl code : 7
Launching Jack server java -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation -cp /srv/jenkins/.jack-server/launcher.jar com.android.jack.launcher.ServerLauncher
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8077: No route to host
waitServerStarted : curl code : 7
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8077: No route to host
waitServerStarted : curl code : 7
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8077: No route to host
```

Can someone please help?

**EDIT**

1. Jack server logs are clean, there are no exceptions or errors.
2. The default ports 8076 and 8077 get blocked as seen in `netstat -nlp`, which indicates the server is indeed started.

   tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8076          :::*                    LISTEN      19180/java
   tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8077          :::*                    LISTEN      19180/java
3. The machine I am building the code upon, is behind a proxy.

Comment: If nothing has worked for you till now, try this solution which worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48780063/1505493

Answer (score 6):

When I was getting Curl error 7 it was accompanied by an SSL error when running jack-diagnose. The following solution worked for me:

1. Edit `java.security` file under `/etc/java-8-openjdk/security/`
2. Remove TLSv1, TLSv1.1 from jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms
3. Restart the jack server:

   - `cd <your-aosp-home-dir>/prebuilts/sdk/tools/`
   - `./jack-admin kill-server`
   - `./jack-admin start-server`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing service and admin ports both in .jack-settings and .jack-server/config.properties and make sure they match.

Jack server may not be able to use the default ports, especially if you are on a server machine where there are more than one user trying to use Jack.

Comment: I tried your approach but it does not help me. any other solution ?

Comment: Well, this problem was related to ports numbers in my case. I'm not sure this is also the case with you. Are you also building on a remote machine, if so, is there any other user on the same remote machine? Are you building dist target? Because dist build uninstalls the jack server and reinstalls it, which clears your port settings and uses default ones, maybe that's why it didn't work.