# I have accidentally uninstalled jack server while building Android AOSP

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, android-source

I am building the Android code for Android Go on my ubuntu 14.04 machine.

While building I got some problems with jack server and I ended up uninstalling the jack server (accidentally).

How do I install the Jack Server again ?

I have tried to install the jack server using the following command:

```
jack-admin install-server jack-launcher.jar jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar
```

However, I get an error:

> Jack server installation not found

Kindly help how do I install Jack Server again.

I have also followed guides from Google Search Result but it has not helped so far.

**Update -1**
After trying the answer from @gaoc I get the following error each time I try to make the build. :

```
[  0% 19/82490] Ensuring Jack server is installed and started
FAILED: setup-jack-server 
/bin/bash -c "(prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin install-server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-launcher.jar prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar  2>&1 || (exit 0) ) && (JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS=\"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation\" prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.11.ALPHA.jar 4.11.ALPHA 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-4.32.CANDIDATE.jar 4.32.CANDIDATE || exit 47 )"
Jack server already installed in "/home/c_sganig/.jack-server"
Communication error with Jack server (3), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log
Communication error with Jack server 3. Try 'jack-diagnose'
Communication error with Jack server 3. Try 'jack-diagnose'
[  0% 34/82490] build out/target/product/msm8909go/emmc_appsboot.mbn
make: Entering directory `/home/c_sganig/code/LA.UM.6.7.r1/bootable/bootloader/lk'
including app/aboot dev/fbcon dev/gcdb/display dev/keys dev/pmic/pm8x41 dev/pmic/pmi8994 dev/qpnp_haptic dev/vib lib/debug lib/heap lib/libc lib/libfdt lib/openssl lib/ptable
including lib/openssl/crypto lib/zlib_inflate
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/c_sganig/code/LA.UM.6.7.r1/bootable/bootloader/lk'
generating ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/config.h
generating ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/system-onesegment.ld
linking ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/lk
../../../prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-ld: warning: /home/c_sganig/code/LA.UM.6.7.r1/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.8/libgcc.a(bpabi.o) uses 32-bit enums yet the output is to use variable-size enums; use of enum values across objects may fail
../../../prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-ld: warning: /home/c_sganig/code/LA.UM.6.7.r1/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.8/libgcc.a(_divdi3.o) uses 32-bit enums yet the output is to use variable-size enums; use of enum values across objects may fail
../../../prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-ld: warning: /home/c_sganig/code/LA.UM.6.7.r1/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.8/libgcc.a(_udivdi3.o) uses 32-bit enums yet the output is to use variable-size enums; use of enum values across objects may fail
generating image: ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/lk.bin
generating listing: ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/lk.lst
generating symbols: ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/lk.sym
generating listing: ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/lk.debug.lst
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 367924  200272  202520  770716   bc29c ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/lk
../../../prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-objcopy -O binary ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/lk ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/lk.bin
generating size map: ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/lk.size
generating stripped elf: ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/lk_s.elf
cp -f ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-msm8909/lk_s.elf ../../../out/target/product/msm8909go/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/../../emmc_appsboot.mbn
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/c_sganig/code/LA.UM.6.7.r1/bootable/bootloader/lk'
make: Leaving directory `/home/c_sganig/code/LA.UM.6.7.r1/bootable/bootloader/lk'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
11:47:18 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (45 seconds) ####
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the solution that helped me with jack server issue:

1. Delete `~/.jack-server` directory and `~/.jack.settings` file. This will be recreated when we run `make` command, so nothing to worry about that.
2. Sync repo again using this command (takes about 30-40 minutes):

   ```
   repo sync -c --no-clone-bundle --no-tags -j4
   ```

   This `-c` option with `sync` command will tell the git about branch you really need instead of all repositories. -jn (-j4 in my case) , here n refers to the number of threads you want.
3. Now build environment , lunch and make as usual.

I will also share another link to Google Group which has some significant information regarding this issue. : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37070263

Answer (score 0):

Show the list of removed packages:

`$ awk '$3 == "remove" { print $1, $2, $4 }' /var/log/dpkg.log | tee list`

If you can find the removed package in the list, then reinstall:

`$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall nameofpackage`

Comment: I tried this and re installed the jack server. Its name was: 'jack-amd64' but it does not work. I have restarted system also.